# WPF: Button Template vs ContentTemplate

Tags: wpf, templates, button

Can I say that usually, in WPF, properties `Template` contains `ContentTemplate`? Or else, whats the difference?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.template.aspx) defines the appearance of the control. [ContentTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplate.aspx) specifies how the content contained in/displayed by a [ContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx) is to be displayed.

Here's a Social.MSDN [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/ba37a337-8d62-4343-9155-0a5093467649) containing an example that shows the difference between the two.

Hope this helps,
Ben

Answer (score 3):

Template's value type is controlTemplate, which defines how control should looks like.

ContentTemplate's value type is dataTemplate, which define the how data should looks like. The similar property is ItemTemplate and CellTemplate.

Answer (score -2):

just have a look at this

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/ba37a337-8d62-4343-9155-0a5093467649