# Passing Values when using Style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `Button` Style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="myBtnStyle">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" 
                               x:Name="myTextBlock" />
                    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1"
                               x:Name="myRectangle" />
</ close everything>
```

Is there any way to pass in values (`Text`, and `Fill` to myTextBlock and myRectangle respectively) when I assign the style to the button?

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=myBtnStyle /*assign Text and Fill here?*/ }"
        Click="myBtn_Click" />
```

If I can't assign it there, then where can I assign it?

Comment: you can use templatebinding to button's content and background if they're not used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be easier to use `Button.Template` (`ControlTemplate`) rather than `Button.ContentTemplate` (`DataTemplate`) here:

[WPF: Button Template vs ContentTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154775/wpf-button-template-vs-contenttemplate)
[Difference between Control Template and DataTemplate in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340108/difference-between-control-template-and-datatemplate-in-wpf)

Then you can use `TemplateBinding` on properties that a button already has, for example use `Button.Content` for the **Text** and `Button.Background` for the **Fill**.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="myBtnStyle" >
    <Setter Property="Template" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" >
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
</ close everything>
```

Usage:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=myBtnStyle}"
        Content="My text here.." Background="Blue" 
        Click="myBtn_Click" />
```

**EDIT:**
Template with image, (mis)using `Button.Tag`:

```xml
...
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" >
    ...
    <!--For some reason, the shorthand "{TemplateBinding Tag}" doesn't work here,
        so we must use the longer "RelativeSource" syntax in this binding:-->
    <Image Grid.Row="1" 
           Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                            Path=Tag}" />
    ...
```

Usage:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=myBtnStyle}"
        Content="My text 1" Tag="http://programming.enthuses.me/1.png" />
<Button Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=myBtnStyle}"
        Content="My text 2" Tag="/MyIcons/Icon01.png" />
```

Comment: Thanks! But if instead of `Rectangle`, it's an `Image`. How do I bind the Image `Source` here?

Comment: A simple solution would be to use the generic `Button.Tag` for the image's `Source`. I have added an example in my answer. Of course, there's only one `Tag` property, so if you need other pieces of information and there are no appropriate properties on `Button`, you can add custom stuff by creating your own custom [Attached Properties](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7149032/1869660), or create your own subclass of `Button`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can use `TemplateBinding` which is a shorthand for writing:

```
{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}
```

In your case, the code would be:

```
<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"  />
<Rectangle Width="50" Height="10" Fill="{TemplateBinding Button.Background}" />
```

Usage:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=myBtnStyle}"
        Content="My text here.." Background="Blue" 
        Click="myBtn_Click" />
```